# Does CoreData encryption require any type of extra documents when submitting to the app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, encryption, appstore-approval

I have seen many questions regarding other types of encryption but I have yet to see one that answers whether or not core data encryption requires you to submit any extra documents when pushing an app to the app store.

I know that apple requires you to click yes to the encryption question even if using apple services for your encryption which is why I am asking what level of encryption is Core Data according to Bureau of Industry and Security.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data as supplied by Apple does not use encryption so just using Core Data does not require any encryption check-box or documentation.

Core Data generally used a SQLite database backend and although there is encoding, that is not encryption in the same manner UTF-8 character encoding is not encryption. Encryption used a key to encrypt data and without the key the data can not be recovered (decrypted).